# Why do I get a 'typeerror' when using inject in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am using this inject method to make a running total of values into an array. I am trying to figure out why I am getting an error.

```
def running_totals(myarray)
 results = []
  myarray.inject([]) do |sum,n|
    results << sum + n
  end
  results
end

p running_totals([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I am getting the error

```
in `+': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array (TypeError)
```

When breaking this method down, isn't this the same as adding two integers and adding that into an array? I'm a bit confused here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not try a simpler solution? e.g. `a.map.with_index {|_,i| a[0..i].reduce(:+) }` this will map into an array by reducing the current element and all preceding elements or even `sum = 0; a.map {|e| sum += e}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `results << sum + n` is an array `results` and it's this that's replacing the `sum` value and so the next iteration you're trying to add a fixnum `n` into an array `sum` ... plus it doesn't help that you're initializing the value of `sum` to be an array.

Make sure that the last executed statement in your inject block is what you want the accumulated value to be.

```
def running_totals(myarray)
  results = []
  results << myarray.inject do |sum, n|
    results << sum
    sum + n
  end
  results
end

p running_totals([1,2,3,4,5])
=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Note that I moved the result of the inject into results array as well, so that the final value is also included, otherwise you'd only have the four values and would be missing the final (15) value.

Answer (score 3):

In the first iteration `sum` will be an array (as you specified an array as the default when calling `inject([])`) and you try to add a number to it. in the `results << sum + n` statement

Instead, set the initial value to `0`, then add, then add the result to the array, then make sure you let `sum` get passed into the next iteration of inject.

```
def running_totals(myarray)
  results = []
  myarray.inject(0) do |sum,n| # First iteration sum will be 0.
    sum += n # Add value to sum.
    results << sum # Push to the result array.
    sum # Make sure sum is passed to next iteration.
  end
  results
end

p running_totals([1,2,3,4,5]) #=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the `inject` block is passed as the first argument the next time the block is called, so those have to match. In your code, you're passing an array as an intital value, and then returning an array; so far, so good. But inside the code block you treat that array parameter (`sum`) as a number, which won't work. Try this:

```
def running_totals(myarray)
  myarray.inject([]) do |results,n|
    results << n + (results.last || 0)
  end
end
```

The `[]` passed as an argument to `inject` becomes the first value of `results`; the first array element (`1` in your example) becomes the first value of `n`. Since `results` is empty, `results.last` is `nil` and the result of `(results.last || 0)` is `0`, which we add to `n` to get 1, which we push onto `results` and then return that newly-modified array value from the block.

The second time into the block, `results` is the array we just returned from the first pass, `[1]`, and `n` is `2`.  This time `results.last` is `1` instead of `nil`, so we add `1` to `2` to get `3` and push that onto the array, returning `[1,3]`.

The third time into the block, `results` is `[1,3]`, and `n` is `3`, so it returns `[1,3,6]`. And so on.

Comment: `results.last || 0` would do the job of that gnarly `if ... then` stuff.

Comment: Good point, edited.  I started with `results.empty? ? 0 : ...` but that was still gnarly...

Comment: Nice answer, very slick!

Answer (score 0):

According to ri, you have to return result of the computation from inject's block.

```
From: enum.c (C Method):
Owner: Enumerable
Visibility: public
Signature: inject(*arg1)
Number of lines: 31

Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary
operation, specified by a block or a symbol that names a
method or operator.

If you specify a block, then for each element in enum
the block is passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element.
If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection
will be passed to the named method of memo.
In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo.
At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the
return value for the method.

If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo,
then uses the first element of collection is used as the initial value
of memo.

Examples:

   # Sum some numbers
   (5..10).reduce(:+)                            #=> 45
   # Same using a block and inject
   (5..10).inject {|sum, n| sum + n }            #=> 45
   # Multiply some numbers
   (5..10).reduce(1, :*)                         #=> 151200
   # Same using a block
   (5..10).inject(1) {|product, n| product * n } #=> 151200
   # find the longest word
   longest = %w{ cat sheep bear }.inject do |memo,word|
     memo.length > word.length ? memo : word
   end
   longest
```

So your sample would work if you return computation result for each iteration, something like this:

```
def running_totals(myarray)
  results = []
  myarray.inject do |sum,n|
    results << sum + n
    results.last # return computation result back to Array's inject
  end
  results
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Quoting the documentation verbatim is kind of a lazy way to answer things.